# SQLite: Multiple aggregate columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, aggregate-functions

I'm a little new to SQL world and still learning the ins and outs of the language.

I have a table with an id, dayOfWeek, and a count for each day.  So any given id might appear in the table up to seven times, with a count of events for each day for each id.  I'd like to restructure the table to have a single row for each id with a column for each day of the week, something like the following obviously incorrect query:

```
SELECT id, sum(numEvents where dayOfWeek = 0), sum(numEvents where dayOfWeek = 1) ... from t;
```

Is there a solid way to approach this?

EDIT:

I'm worried I may not have been very clear.  The table would ideally be structured something like this:

```
id | Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday
0  | 13     | 45     | 142     | 3         | 36       | 63     | 15336
1  | 17     | 25     | 45      | 364       | 37       | 540    | 0
```

So event 0 occurred 13 times on Sunday, 45 on Monday, etc...  My current table looks like this:

```
id | dayOfWeek | count
0  | 0         | 13
0  | 1         | 45
0  | 2         | 142
0  | 3         | 3
0  | 4         | 36
0  | 5         | 63
0  | 6         | 15336
1  | 0         | 17
1  | 1         | 25
...
```

Hope that helps clear up what I'm after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is verbose, but should work (generic [ideone sql demo](http://ideone.com/Oca4G9) unfortunately SqlLite on SqlFiddle is down at the moment):

```
SELECT id, 
    SUM(case when dayofweek = 1 then numevents else 0 end) as Day1Events,
    SUM(case when dayofweek = 2 then numevents else 0 end) as Day2Events,
    SUM(case when dayofweek = 3 then numevents else 0 end) as Day3Events 
        --, etc...
FROM EventTable
GROUP BY ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT dayOfWeek, sum(numEvents) as numberOfEvents
FROM t
GROUP BY dayOfWeek;
```